# Is it a good practice to combine design patterns in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Currently I'm working on my private project(for learning) which is a simple To Do List. I'm trying to use the modular pattern (revealing module pattern, to be specific). The image below shows ma general idea how I'm going to build it.

[Image of how my app looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKHiB.png)

So each module will be in a separate js file where each module looks like:

```
var TaskModule = (function () { 

  function someFunction(parameter) {
    tasks = newTasks;
  }

}
```

And there is the question: what if we want to create something like separate file with lets say 'helpers function'. It's not comfortable writing in each module something like:

```
var someElement = document.getElementById('id')
```

I have my helper function (this function is just an example):

```
var someElement = byId('id');
```

Of course I can create HelpersModule in the same way like the others but then I will have to call my function this way:

```
var someElement = HelpersModule.byId('id');
```

Which causes that my help function doesn't make sense anymore, it's not shorter than original version with document.getElementById. So to avoid writing this prefix 'HelpersModule' every time I call my helper function, I designed my HelpersModule like this:

```
(function(window) {

    window.byId = function (selector, scope) {
      return (scope || document).getElementById(selector);
    };

})(window);
```

Now everything works fine but the way I create HelpersModule is not consistent with the others modules. Is it a bad practice to create modules in differents way or it's completely OK?

Comment: Does your `HelpersModule.byID()` do the same thing as `document.getElementById()`?

Comment: @demogorgon.net yes, it does, but this is just an example

Comment: If your modules are intended to do different things (one initialises an object while the other provides global variables), it's no wonder they look different. Using different ways for that is totally OK. I would recommend to avoid as many global variables as you can, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a utility module (like your `HelpersModule`):

```js
const HelpersModule = {
  byId: id => document.getElementById(id),
  byTag: tag => Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName(tag))
};
```

... and somewhere in your other code, assign the helper functions you need to a local variable:

```js
// ...
const byId = HelpersModule.byId; // if you only need 'byId'
const element = byId('my-id');
// ...
```

or, using destructuring:

```js
const { byId } = HelpersModule; // if you only need 'byId'
const element = byId('my-id');
```

or

```js
const { byId, byTag } = HelpersModule; // if you need both
const element = byId('my-id');
const allSpans = byTag('span');
```

Comment: this is the right idea, but he hasn't made any indication that he's using ECMAScript 6.

Comment: @Sahuagin come on, `const` has [96.94%](http://caniuse.com/#feat=const) global support, and I provided an alternative to destructuring. If the OP really runs into problems with `const`, he can easily replace it with `var`. Was that the reason for the downvote?

Comment: There is no problem the answer is in ES6. Your solution is really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I did not downvote, no. Maybe it doesn't matter because he didn't specify a version.

Comment: (i just find it slightly jarring to see a question written in 'classic javascript' and an answer written in 'newfangled javascript')

Comment: @Sahuagin I did some research; [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332817/are-answers-using-latest-not-widely-supported-ecmascript-features-discouraged) question is one year old, but the consensus of the community seems to be that ES2015 is OK, but you can leave a note if some features that you are using are new. I would do that if it wouldn't be superfluous now that the OP said he's OK with ES2015.

Answer (score 0):

If both

```
var someElement = document.getElementById('id')
```

and

```
var someElement = HelpersModule.byId('id');
```

do the same thing, then I'd recommend just using the first one instead of creating a new module.  This way you will keep true to your module model and you only have to add one line of code per module.  Creating a whole new module plus still writing one line of code per module is not necessary.  Did this help/did I understand your question?

**Edit:**

I see what you mean now.  You want to know if you should make a separate module that holds *all* helper methods for every single module.  In this case, it is still better to keep your helper methods only within the files that they are needed in.  So if you have a helper method that is use in only one file, and can only be used for that file, it should just stay in that file.  It is easier to keep track of all of your methods if they are in the file that requires them.  It also prevents you from having to jump back and forth between files to find the methods you are looking for.

So just keep helper methods within the files that require them (the files that call them) instead of another module.  It will get to confusing later on when your files are thousands of lines of code.

Comment: Of course in this example, there is no point to create another module just for one function, I do agree. But this is just an example. What If I have many helpers functions, I may need such module for them.

Comment: I made an edit to my answer, let me know if that makes sense. cheers @pastuszkam

Comment: In this approach, I may need to duplicate code of some functions in each file which needs these functions. I would like to avoid any duplications.

Comment: @pastuszkam if you will be duplicating it among several files then yes, a new file to hold them would be keeping your code DRY (dont repeat yourself)